# iPhone silencing a few calls after a few seconds

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 14 pro max silences a few calls after a few seconds but on some calls it rings for the whole time. iOS 16.1.1 My girlfriend has iPhone 14 iOS 16.5 same problem
https://youtu.be/gbI8FriHJxI

Comment: Try changing your ringtone to something else (a factory one).  Does the problem persist?